# Creating totals result from a calculated column. SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to create 1 total for my "calcColumn". I am calculating new values based off of column 4 and resultLimit column. I cannot seem to get any grouping or rollups to work, I did not include them because it was a mess and likely VERY wrong. Any help would be GREAT! Thanks much!

```
SELECT
  col1
 ,col2
 ,col3
 ,col4
 ,resultNum
 ,resultLimit
 ,CASE
    WHEN col4 = 'N' THEN (.5 * CONVERT(FLOAT, resultLimit))
    ELSE (R.resultNum)
  END AS calcColumn
FROM
  table1
JOINS
  ...
JOINS
  ...
WHERE
  Col1 = 'BlahBlah'
ORDER BY
  col2 ASC;
```

Comment: You need to define " I cannot seem to get any grouping or rollups to work". What does that mean? do you get an error? Wrong results? We are going to need some details to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You can wrap a select around this one. At that level your calccolumn is as any other.

Comment: Start with a basic set of data and a complete definition of what you are trying to do. "Total" generally means "sum" but your stub of a query only shows a simple calculation. And writing "JOINS JOINS" does not inspire confidence, nor does the casting of resultLimit (in just one branch) in your case expression. If you want help, you need to make an attempt to provide sufficient information for others to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a select around it worked a charm. Sorry for being so general....